# Need help positioning HREF images

Tags: html

I'm really new to coding HTML but I took a couples classes a few years so I'm barely familiar. I've been looking up the code to do anything I'm trying to do. I'm having trouble positioning images that have links on them.

Here's my code for the images so far:

```
<a href="https://www.soundcloud.com/love_seat"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/OSe8qRJ.png" onMouseOver="this.src='https://i.imgur.com/HxtpEDz.png';" onMouseOut="this.src='https://i.imgur.com/OSe8qRJ.png';" width="200" height="200" title="music" alt="Music"></a>
<a href="https://grnbrier.bigcartel.com/"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/DwNXARK.png" onmouseover="this.src='https://i.imgur.com/rhseWJq.png';" onmouseout="this.src='https://i.imgur.com/DwNXARK.png';" class="image-margin" width="200" height="200" title="clothing" alt="Clothing"></a>
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/grnbrier/"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/QZetL5S.png" onmouseover="this.src='https://i.imgur.com/bxD1xCk.png';" onmouseout="this.src='https://i.imgur.com/QZetL5S.png';" width="200" height="200" title="socialmedia" alt="Socialmedia"></a>
```

This looks like:
[wrongcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFQzW.png)

I need the CD disk case to be to the left of the mannequin. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Seems like you can just that first anchor where the second anchor tag is. So just swap lines one and two.

Comment: What does your CSS look like?

Comment: Please also share your CSS code so that others can help you.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of work, you need to use **HTML Image Maps**, here I made this for you

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFQzW.png" alt="" usemap="#map" width="800" height="200">

  <map name="map">
    <area shape="rect" coords="6,54,115,154" title="music" alt="Music" href="https://www.soundcloud.com/love_seat">
    <area shape="rect" coords="477,52,572,158" title="clothing" alt="Clothing" href="https://grnbrier.bigcartel.com/">
    <area shape="rect" coords="587,49,712,158" title="socialmedia" alt="Socialmedia" href="https://www.instagram.com/grnbrier/">
  </map>
```

**Note**:

I have set the size of the image to 800x200 if you want to change that you need to change the coords of each area, just do some calculations.

Here is a more precise map

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFQzW.png" alt="" usemap="#map" width="800" height="200">

  <map name="map">
    <area shape="poly" coords="6,54,118,63,113,155,7,143" title="music" alt="Music" href="https://www.soundcloud.com/love_seat">
    <area shape="poly" coords="508,70,509,53,524,53,524,71,538,74,537,101,544,102,549,121,539,110,536,116,548,124,565,143,573,159,536,158,559,146,521,121,483,143,483,153,476,139,488,124,499,188,496,114,491,117,492,104,498,97,493,75" title="clothing" alt="Clothing" href="https://grnbrier.bigcartel.com/">
    <area shape="poly" coords="615,48,685,48,700,55,711,68,711,131,708,145,688,161,613,160,598,153,588,136,588,75,597,57" title="socialmedia" alt="Socialmedia" href="https://www.instagram.com/grnbrier/">
  </map>
```

I felt like I'm recreating the images in SVG :D

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to align the images to the right of the window, then you could use `style="float: right"`:

```
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/grnbrier/"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/QZetL5S.png" onmouseover="this.src='https://i.imgur.com/bxD1xCk.png';" onmouseout="this.src='https://i.imgur.com/QZetL5S.png';" width="200" height="200" title="socialmedia" alt="Socialmedia" style="float: right"></a>
<a href="https://grnbrier.bigcartel.com/"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/DwNXARK.png" onmouseover="this.src='https://i.imgur.com/rhseWJq.png';" onmouseout="this.src='https://i.imgur.com/DwNXARK.png';" class="image-margin" width="200" height="200" title="clothing" alt="Clothing" style="float: right"></a>
<a href="https://www.soundcloud.com/love_seat"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/OSe8qRJ.png" onMouseOver="this.src='https://i.imgur.com/HxtpEDz.png';" onMouseOut="this.src='https://i.imgur.com/OSe8qRJ.png';" width="200" height="200" title="music" alt="Music" style="float: right"></a>
```