# <!DOCTYPE html> tag is messing up my sliced layout from Photoshop

Tags: javascript, html, css, photoshop

I feel like I'm absolutely stumped. I have tried the height: 100%; fix, but that is not working. Also, my html and css are both valid according to W3C. Finally, I read that this kind of layout is pretty depreciated, which doesn't help, but I've spent so much time on this project that I'd like to get past this hiccup so I can have a decent final product.

Here is the live code...
http://valeriehosler.com

**Here is my HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Next to Normal Story Map by Valerie Hosler</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather:wght@900&amp;display=swap">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <table id="Table_01">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="11">
        <img src="images/Next-to-Normal-New_01.gif" width="1440" height="242" alt=""></td>
      <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="242" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" rowspan="3">
        <img src="images/Next-to-Normal-New_02.gif" width="496" height="316" alt=""></td>
      <td>
        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Diana2"><img src="images/Diana.gif" width="93" height="68" alt=""></a>
      </td>
      <td colspan="3" rowspan="2">
        <img src="images/Next-to-Normal-New_04.gif" width="389" height="204" alt=""></td>
      <td>
        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Dan2"><img src="images/Gabe.gif" width="93" height="68" alt=""></a>
      </td>
      <td colspan="3" rowspan="3">
        <img src="images/Next-to-Normal-New_06.gif" width="369" height="316" alt=""></td>
      <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="68" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="6">
        <img src="images/Next-to-Normal-New_07.gif" width="93" height="590" alt=""></td>
      <td rowspan="6">
        <img src="images/Next-to-Normal-New_08.gif" width="93" height="590" alt=""></td>
      <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="136" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="5">
        <img src="images/Next-to-Normal-New_09.gif" width="29" height="454" alt=""></td>
      <td rowspan="2">
        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Logo2"><img src="images/Logo.gif" width="294" height="154" alt=""></a>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="5">
        <img src="images/Next-to-Normal-New_11.gif" width="66" height="454" alt=""></td>
      <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="112" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4">
        <img src="images/Next-to-Normal-New_12.gif" width="272" height="342" alt=""></td>
      <td rowspan="3">
        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Gabe2"><img src="images/Gabe-14.gif" width="85" height="83" alt=""></a>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="4">
        <img src="images/Next-to-Normal-New_14.gif" width="139" height="342" alt=""></td>
      <td rowspan="4">
        <img src="images/Next-to-Normal-New_15.gif" width="153" height="342" alt=""></td>
      <td rowspan="2">
        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Natalie2"><img src="images/Natalie.gif" width="81" height="79" alt=""></a>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="4">
        <img src="images/Next-to-Normal-New_17.gif" width="135" height="342" alt=""></td>
      <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="42" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">
        <img src="images/Next-to-Normal-New_18.gif" width="294" height="300" alt=""></td>
      <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="37" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">
        <img src="images/Next-to-Normal-New_19.gif" width="81" height="263" alt=""></td>
      <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="4" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="images/Next-to-Normal-New_20.gif" width="85" height="259" alt=""></td>
      <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="259" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <div id="Diana2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h1 class="modal-title">Diana</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
            <p style="font-size: 16px !important; margin-top: 0 !important;">
              Diana is the matriarch of the family. She's witty, electric, creative, and she also has Bipolar I disorder. Throughout the musical, she struggles to juggle being a caretaker to her family and herself.
            </p>
            <p style="font-size: 16px !important;">
              In <i>I Miss the Mountains</i>, Diana reminisces about what it felt like to be off psychiatric medication and be able to "see" (AKA hallucinate) her deceased son again. In the end, she decides to dispose of her medication, with
              disastrous results.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="center">
            <video width="320" height="240" controls>
              <source src="Mountains.mp4" type="video/mp4">
              Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btncenter">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Back to the Story Map</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="Dan2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h1 class="modal-title">Dan</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
            <p style="font-size: 16px !important; margin-top: 0 !important;">
              Dan is the patriarch of the family. He's loyal, consistent, but also incredibly mentally fatigued. Throughout the musical, he is the glue that holds the family together.
            </p>
            <p style="font-size: 16px !important;">
              In <i>I Am the One</i>, Dan reminds Diana that he has always been there for her. However, Diana is torn between him and her deceased son.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="center">
            <video width="320" height="240" controls>
              <source src="One.mp4" type="video/mp4">
              Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btncenter">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Back to the Story Map</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="Gabe2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h1 class="modal-title">Gabe</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
            <p style="font-size: 16px !important; margin-top: 0 !important;">
              Gabe is Diana and Dan's deceased, infant son. In the musical, Diana hallucinates a late-teenage aged version of Gabe when she is unmedicated. He's portayed as attractive, charismatic, and manipulative.
            </p>
            <p style="font-size: 16px !important;">
              In <i>I'm Alive</i>, Gabe attempts to convince Diana that he is more than a hallucination.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="center">
            <video width="320" height="240" controls>
              <source src="Alive.mp4" type="video/mp4">
              Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btncenter">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Back to the Story Map</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="Natalie2" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h1 class="modal-title">Natalie</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
            <p style="font-size: 16px !important; margin-top: 0!important;">
              Natalie is Diana and Dan's living, teenage daughter. In the musical, Diana describes her as a "genius, but a freak". She dreams of escaping her family.
            </p>
            <p style="font-size: 16px !important;">
              In <i>Everything Else</i>, Natalie sings while playing one of Mozart's sonatas for piano. She describes how her musical aspirations make everything else in her life disappear.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="center">
            <video width="320" height="240" controls>
              <source src="EverythingElse.mp4" type="video/mp4">
              Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btncenter">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Back to the Story Map</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="Logo2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h1 class="modal-title">Next to Normal</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
            <p style="font-size: 16px !important; margin-top: 0 !important;">
              Next to Normal is a 2008 rock musical that was created by Brian Yorkey. It follows a woman with worsening Bipolar I disorder and her suburban family.
            </p>
            <p style="font-size: 16px !important;">
              In <i>Just Another Day</i>, the audience is introduced to the entire family. Though it seems like everyone is there, it is eventually revealed that Gabe is actually deceased, but manifests as a hallucination.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="center">
            <video width="320" height="240" controls>
              <source src="N2NSONG.mp4" type="video/mp4">
              Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btncenter">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Back to the Story Map</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="hello" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h1 class="modal-title">Next to Normal</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
            <p style="font-size: 16px !important;">
              Welcome to the Next to Normal Story Map! I created this interactive map because I love this musical and I wanted to share a slice of it with you. Click on the GIFs to learn more about the show while listening to great music!
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="btncenter2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Back to the Story Map</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    $(window).on('load', function() {
      $('#hello').modal('show');
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

**And here is my CSS**

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  background: #000000;
}

h1 {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #7f479e;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

h4 {
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  border: 0;
}

p {
  padding: 0;
}

table#Table_01 {
  border-spacing: 0;
  height: 900px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 1441px;
}

.center {
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.btncenter {
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 0 25px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.btncenter2 {
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 0 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn-primary, .btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:active, .btn-primary:visited {
  background-color: #7f479e !important;
  border-color: #000000 !important;
}

.modal-header {
  border-bottom: 0 solid #ffffff !important;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

I appreciate any and all feedback!

Comment: Can you describe what the problem is? I'm not familiar with Photoshop's sliced layout.

Comment: Sure. Essentially, my layout is comprised of multiple sections of one image that Photoshop organized into a table. The pieces of the larger picture should perfectly combine like a puzzle, but every time I add the <!DOCTYPE html tag, spaces in the layout form. If I don't add the tag and rely on quirks mode, it looks fine.

Comment: Why don't you just use the whole image as one, why to slice it?!

Comment: This particular project has to be like a story map where the user can click on different parts of the map and view more media.

Comment: For this you can use image maps instead, here is an [**example**](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images_imagemap.asp) on **W3Schools**

Comment: Oh my gosh, I should've done that in the first place. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome, here is a [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61033699/13158151) of mine on Image maps

Comment: Just add `vertical-align: top` to the `td` styles. That fixes it just fine

Answer (score 0):

Remove the doctype declaration.

For your next project, don't use a tool such as Photoshop for generating HTML, because as you have learned it isn't any good at it. Use a doctype declaration.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Will this make my project show up strangely in different browsers?

Comment: @vlhst863 You'd have to check, which is easily done. The reason it looks bad when you add it is because the doctype declaration is typically tied to rendering modes (with Photoshop having only prepared for one in this case), and to a certain degree browsers have long conspired to have similar rendering modes based on certain parts of the source. Without a doctype declaration you are in "quirks mode".

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you for your thorough explanation.

Comment: @vlhst863 This layout could be very easily accomplished with HTML & CSS by hand. You would want the base black and white building image as a single image file to do it. If you made another question seeking assistance on how to do that, you would probably get a lot of decent help.